# Importing Existing Event Bus SST / CDK not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

We are using SST to deploy our AWS stack.  I need to be able to import an event bus from a different account and attach
a rule to it.

The SST construct I am using to import the bus:

```js
  const importedBus = new EventBus(stack, 'event-bus', {
    cdk: {
      eventBus: events.EventBus.fromEventBusArn(
        stack,
        'imported-bus',
        'arn:aws:events:us-east-2:11111111111:event-bus/imported-bus'
      ),
    },
  });
```

And I am trying to attach a rule with my SQS queue as a target:

```js
  importedBus.addRules(stack, {
    subscription: {
      pattern: {
        detailType: ['message'],
      },
      targets: {
        subscriberQueue: eventsSubscriberQueue,
      },
    },
  });
```

This pattern works with event buses defined in the same account without issue:

```js
    const otherBus = new EventBus(stack, 'other-event-bus', {
    cdk: {
      eventBus: events.EventBus.fromEventBusName(
        stack,
        'importedBus-other-bus',
        'other-event-bus',
      ),
    },
  });
```

When I deploy the stack (we are using Github actions) - I am getting an error

```
  ➜  App:     app
     Stage:   dev
     Region:  us-east-2
     Account: 111111111111
  
  ✔  Building...
  
  |  AppStack PUBLISH_ASSETS_COMPLETE 
  |  AppStack imported-event-bus/Parameter_eventBusName AWS::SSM::Parameter CREATE_COMPLETE 
  |  AppStack AppMessageCenterSubscription AWS::Events::Rule CREATE_FAILED Resource handler returned message: "Event bus imported-bus does not exist. (Service: EventBridge, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 56e766bf-3387-4b84-a0eb-5dda966cd86e)" (RequestToken: bc9f18c9-d467-3537-eb71-e368f8900692, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)
  |  AppStack imported-event-bus/Parameter_eventBusName AWS::SSM::Parameter DELETE_COMPLETE 
  |  AppStack AppMessageCenterSubscription AWS::Events::Rule DELETE_COMPLETE 
  |  AppStack AWS::CloudFormation::Stack UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE 
  ⠋  Deploying...
  
  ✖  Errors
     AppStack UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE
     AppMessageCenterSubscription: Resource handler returned message: "Event bus imported-bus does not exist. (Service: EventBridge, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 56e766bf-3387-4b84-a0eb-5dda966cd86e)" (RequestToken: bc9f18c9-d467-3537-eb71-e368f8900692, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)
  
   ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
  Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have followed this instructions from aws on [Permissions for Amazon EventBridge event buses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-bus-perms.html#eb-event-bus-permissions-manage)

And added a resource based policy to the event bus in the account I am trying to write a rule to:

```json
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "AllowAccountToManageRulesTheyCreated",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": "1111111111"
        },
        "Action": [
          "events:PutRule",
          "events:PutTargets",
          "events:DeleteRule",
          "events:RemoveTargets",
          "events:DisableRule",
          "events:EnableRule",
          "events:TagResource",
          "events:UntagResource",
          "events:DescribeRule",
          "events:ListTargetsByRule",
          "events:ListTagsForResource"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:events:us-east-2:2222222222:rule/imported-event-bus",
        "Condition": {
          "StringEqualsIfExists": {
            "events:creatorAccount": "1111111111"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I know SST uses CDK under the hood - so this should work.  The second paragraph from the docs state:

*...that using an ARN as a parameter to reference cross-account buses...you can call PutRule to create a rule on a a event bus in a different account without needing to assume a role.*

[image]